# How to trigger an action for the calendar events start time in android?

Tags: android, calendar

Actually I need to trigger an action(Intent) for the calendar events start time.

I had used the Calendar database to read the events title,start time and end time.

By passing the first start time to the alarm manager, I was able to trigger my action only once. My main problem is how to continue this process by passing different time intervals to the Alarm Manager.

Or is there any better solution to notify the action(Intent) ??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no intent to act on using a broadcast receiver.

You can however,  [read the event instances](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#instances) manually and [schedule background tasks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) using the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25393550/2614353) on a similar question