# how to respond to start of event in user's calendar

Tags: android

I want to perform an action when an event in the user's calendar starts or ends. Is there a BroadcastReceiver or something that can help me do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is good source for reading calendar in android developer's site. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#instances
As Querying a calendar.
And there is good tutorial for scheduling tasks at background http://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/

EDIT:

Use

```
cursor_event.getLong(cursor_event.getColumnIndex("dtstart"));
```

to get time the event starts in UTC millis since epoch.

To get event end time use

```
cursor_event.getLong(cursor_event.getColumnIndex("dtend"));
```

All event columns you can find here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#DTEND
And of course you must use this columnindexs dtstart etc. you must you broadcast receiver i gave the link above sitepoint.com
Let me know if your issue solved.

Comment: thanks. I was actually wondering if there was some sort of intent filter that could detect a calendar event starting. Do you know anything about that?